# Cube root of a number, C++

Tags: c++, math

I would like to ask a very short question, and it is as follows: in finding the cube root of a number (both neg. and pos.) in C++, how does one restrict the output to real solutions only?
I am currently writing a program to solve a cubic with Cardano's formula, and one of the intermediate variables I am using randomly outputs the complex and real cube roots - and I only need the real roots.

(E.g. in evaluating the cube root of -0.0127378, the three roots would be 0.11677095+0.202253218i, −0.2335419, 0.11677095−0.202253218i - I wish to ignore the complex ones for substitution into a later formula)

Thank you!

EDIT: Solved it! :) I created a signum function and tweaked the sign after taking the power of the absolute value of SPrime and TPrime, so now it carries forward only the real cube root.

```
/* ... */

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int signum(std::complex<double> z)
{
    if (z.real() < 0 || z.imag() < 0) return -1;
    else if (z.real() >= 0 || z.imag() >= 0) return 1;
}

// POST: The function is intended to solve a cubic equation with       coefficients a, b, c and d., such that
//      ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0. If there exist infinitely many solutions, we output -1, i.e. if a=b=c=d=0
//      (trivial solution).

void solve(std::complex<double> a, std::complex<double> b,   std::complex<double> c, std::complex<double> d, std::complex<double>& x1, std::complex<double>& x2, std::complex<double>& x3)
{
    complex<double> i = complex<double> (0, 1.0);
    // Consider implementing Cardano's method for obtaining the solution of a degree 3 polynomial, as suggested
   // We must hence define the discriminant D of such an equation through complex doubles Q and R
    std::complex<double> Q;
    Q = (3.0*a*c - pow(b, 2)) / (9.0*pow(a, 2));
    cout << "Q=" << Q << endl;

    std::complex<double> R;
    R = (9.0*a*b*c - 27.0*d*pow(a, 2) - 2.0*pow(b, 3)) / (54.0*pow(a, 3));
    cout << "R=" << R << endl;

    std::complex<double> D;
    D = pow(Q, 3) + pow(R, 2);

    // Possible types of output for discriminant
    if (abs(D) < 0.0)
    {
        cout << "The cubic has three distinct, real roots." << endl;
    }

    else if (abs(D) == 0.0)
    {
        cout << "The cubic has three real roots, at least two of which are equal." << endl;
    }

    else if (abs(D) > 0.0)
    {
        cout << "The cubic has one real root and two complex conjugate roots." << endl;
    }

    // Defining two further complex double variables S and T, which are required to obtain the final solution for x1, x2 and x3
    std::complex<double> S;
    std::complex<double> SPrime;
    SPrime = R+sqrt(Q*Q*Q + R*R);
    cout << "SPrime=" << SPrime << endl;

    if (signum(SPrime) == -1)
    {
        S = (-1)*pow(abs(SPrime), 0.3333333333333);        
    }

    else if (signum(SPrime) == 1)
    {
        S = pow(abs(SPrime), 0.3333333333333);
    }

    cout << "S=" << S << endl;

    std::complex<double> T;
    std::complex<double> TPrime;
    TPrime = (R-sqrt(Q*Q*Q + R*R));

    if (signum(TPrime) == -1)
    {
        T = (-1)*pow(abs(TPrime), 0.3333333333333);        
    }

    else if (signum(TPrime) == 1)
    {
        T = pow(abs(TPrime), 0.3333333333333);
    }

    cout << "T=" << T << endl;
    cout << "TPrime= " << TPrime << endl;

    // Expressions for the solutions
    x1 = S + T - (b/(3.0*a));
    x2 = (-0.5)*(S + T) - (b/(3.0*a)) + (sqrt(3.0)*0.5)*(S - T)*i;
    x3 = conj(x2);

    if (abs(x1) < 0.000000000001)
    {
        x1 = 0;
    }
}

// Driver code
int main ()
{
    // Taking user input for a, b, c and d
    std::complex<double> a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x3;
    cout << "Please enter the coefficients of the polynomial in successive order." << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;

    solve (a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x3);
    cout << x1 << ", " << x2 << ", " << x3 << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C++11?

Comment: If so, `#include <cmath>` has the function `cbrt` which returns the real cube root for any number.

Comment: It doesn't matter which cube root you take, so long as you make both choices of cube root consistently.

Comment: Also, you should realize that solving a cubic with Cardano's formula *requires* using nonreal numbers when all three roots are real.

Comment: @EliSadoff Thank you for the quick reply :) I tried using <cmath>, but because most of my variables are std::complex<double>'s, I cannot use cbrt :(

Comment: @Hurkyl The thing is, it computes some roots of the cubic correctly, but it fails to work for all (outputs wrong solutions) cubics, and this is because the part where I need to take a cube root does not always give the real cube root of a number. :( Here is where the problem is:   std::complex<double> S;
    std::complex<double> SPrime;
    SPrime = R+sqrt(Q*Q*Q + R*R);
    
    //Here it goes wrong! This part needs to output real cube roots of a number
    S = pow(SPrime, 0.3333333333333);

Comment: @Noble: Like I said, you just have to do it consistently. Usually, calculation strategies do this "automatically" by replacing one of the cube roots with a division: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula You *don't* need the real cube root even when one exists: in fact each choice of cube root gives you a different one of the three solutions.

Comment: @Hurkyl I used the breakdown suggested here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula .. The main issue is that I get solutions for the cubic, which are not correct - but it works for some cases. e.g. it may work just fine for x^3 - 1 = 0, but not for 6x^3 + 4x^2 + 7x = 0..

Comment: The roots are computed correctly, they are just not the ones of the three possibilities that you want. The definition is that the root is chosen that is closest to the real axis, i.e., has positive real part and smallest (positive when in doubt) angle of all roots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem as you're stating it can be solved trivially (with real numbers the cubic root of -x is the opposite of the cubic root of x):

```
double cuberoot(double x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return -pow(-x, 1.0/3.0);
    } else if (x > 0) {
        return pow(x, 1.0/3.0);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
 }
```

If the input is instead in general complex `z` and you're looking for the "most real" (principal) cubic root the same reasoning can be applied using complex `pow` version to either `z` or `-z` depending on the sign of the real part:

```
std::complex<double> cuberoot(std::complex<double> z) {
    if (z.real() < 0) {
        return -pow(-z, 1.0/3.0);
    } else {
        return pow(z, 1.0/3.0);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Oh dear! Haha makes me feel so daft! Thank you for that. :) I made a signum function which does the sign check you suggested, and now it works! :)

Comment: With your last two functions, the result for `-1` should be `0.5*(1+i*sqrt(3))`, as they do both the same, calculate the angle as 180° and divide by 3 to get 60°. The first function gives what was desired and can be expanded to complex number by checking the real part.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code:

- As you allow complex coefficients, the discussion of the discriminant becomes slightly meaningless, it is only of value for real coefficients.
- `abs(D)` is always non-negative. If `D==0`, then there is a double root, more can not be said in the case of complex coefficients.
- You can avoid a lot of code by utilizing that `S*T=-Q`. One would have to care that the computation of `u=T^3` returns the larger of the roots of `0==u^2 - 2*R*u - Q^3` or `(u-R)^2 = D = R^2+Q^3`

  ```
  rtD = sqrt(D);
  T = cuberoot( R + (abs(R+rtD)>=abs(R-rtD)) ? rtD : -rtD );
  S = (abs(T)<epsilon) ? 0 : -Q/T;
  ```

  Because of `abs(R)<=abs(T)^3` and `abs(D)<=abs(T)^6`
  one gets also `abs(Q)<=2^(1/3)*abs(T)^2` resulting in

  ```
  abs(S)=abs(Q/T) <= 2^(1/3)*abs(T)
  ```

  For `S=-Q/T` to fail one would thus need a serious case 
  of extremely small floating point numbers in `R`, `Q` 
  and thus `T`. Quantitatively, for `double` even 
  the threshold `epsilon=1e-150` should be safe.

---

On cube root variants:

For esthetic reasons one might want `T` as close to a coordinate axis as possible. A cube root function achieving this would be

```
std::complex<double> cuberoot(std::complex<double> z) {
    double r=abs(z), phi=arg(z);
    double k = round(2*phi/pi); 
    // closest multiple of pi/2
    // an equivalent angle is (phi-k*pi/2) - k*3*pi/2
    return std::polar( pow(r,1.0/3), (phi-k*pi/2)/3 - k*pi/2 );
}
```

so that `abs(phi-k*pi/2)<=pi/4`, and thus the angle to the next coordinate axis of the cube root is smaller than `pi/12=15°`. `cuberoot(i)` returns `-i`, `cuberoot(-1)` returns `-1`, a point at 60° returns a cube root at (60°-90°)/3-90°=-100°, etc.