# How to know the result of Complex has one or more real roots

Tags: c#, math, mathematical-expressions

I want to use Complex to calculate the minus pow.

As $(-10)^(1/3)$ that use the Math.Pow will get the NAN.

But when I use Complex.Pow, I can get the result.

```
        Complex c = Complex.Pow(-10, 1.0/3);
        var r = c.Magnitude;//2.1544346900318843
```

But the real result is -2.1544346900318843.

I don't know the result is positive for the Magnitude is Abs.

I can't add `-1*` in all the result for the pow can make the result is positive.

`(-10)^(2/3)` should get the positive result.

#### How can I judge the result is positive and To determine whether there is a real solution?

See:https://stackoverflow.com/a/43539898/6116637

--

edit

(-10)^(2/3)

```
    Imaginary   4.0197338438308483  double
    Magnitude   4.6415888336127784  double
    Phase   2.0943951023931953  double
    Real    -2.3207944168063883 double
```

[image]

(-10)^(1/3)

```
    Imaginary   1.8657951723620641  double
    Magnitude   2.1544346900318843  double
    Phase   1.0471975511965976  double
    Real    1.0772173450159421  double
```

[image]

How to calculate it,see:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cube root of a number, C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439739/cube-root-of-a-number-c)

Comment: @LutzL That is C++ but I use the C# and Complex that is the Microsoft lib.

Comment: But the conceptual problem of powers of non-positive and complex numbers, as well as its solution, a cube root working on the whole real axis, are the same.

Comment: @LutzL But I dont know why (-10)^(2/3)!=((-10)^2)^(1/3)

Comment: @LutzL We can make the Math.Abs(base) for I should know that whether there is a real solution.

Comment: Rational powers of complex numbers are a tricky business, non-rational powers are impossible to define correctly (but you still get "a" result that you might call "the" result). There is no way to select a branch of these multi-valued functions that is consistent under the "naive" rules of powers. See sqrt(1/-1)!= sqrt(1)/sqrt(-1) and similar.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to change from "positive" to "has one or more real roots". That might get some upvotes, since it is a (interesting in my opinion) question of how to implement efficiently in code or which libs help.

Comment: Is your question specifically only about the cube root of negative numbers or generally on rational powers of complex numbers?

Comment: @Yunnosch Thx for your suggestion.

Comment: @LutzL I want to make a software that can draw the function.

Comment: You want to draw the (in my opinion) 2D result of a function on a 2D input? Be sure to plan what you want to draw and how. A 3D diagram would allow you for example to draw one attribute (e.g. magnitude) of a complex result, as the height of a surface over a 2D input area. But you seem to be heading elsewhere. Maybe a multitude of (kind of) cylindrical surfaces (one for each root) around an axis representing the pure real input.

Comment: @Yunnosch In order to avoid being said that advertising, I dont want to send a link to the software.But I need to draw the plane graphics to help teacher to teach and make the student easy to know about function.

Comment: What function? Each function has a domain and a range, for powers with real exponents both are the positive real numbers. Only in exceptional cases can this be extended to the negative reals.

Comment: @LutzL I want draw a function like you wirte the string to google that will show you a image.

Comment: Then play around with google and let it not only show x^(1/3) but also x^(1/3.5) and similar.

Comment: @LutzL Are you know that the google's algorithm？

Comment: Compare x^(1/3.5) to x^(2/7), try also x^(2/6). Apparently, they parse the exponent as fraction if it is a fraction of integers and check if the denominator of the reduced fraction is an odd number. Only then are values for negative arguments computed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142578/discussion-between-lindexi-and-lutzl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In complex numbers there are three cubical roots for any number.
For negative numbers (negative real part, no imaginary part), the three roots are arranged like this.

```
                                       X1  
                                      /  
                                     /  
                                    /  
                                   /
                    X2------------0  
                                   \  
                                    \  
                                     \  
                                      \  
                                       X3
```

They all have the same magnitude, which is practically the distance from (0,0)==0+i0.
X1 and X3 have the same real part, which is half of the real part of X2.
X1 and X3 have the same absolute value of the imaginary part, with different sign.
X2 has no imaginary part. The real part of X2 is minus the magnitude.

So, the real part of X2, which is negative, is not the magnitude.
The magnitude, by definition, is positive for all of the roots.

Note that the square of the three roots do not necessarily have positive real parts either.
Especially the square of the first root (`X1`), being the first in mathematical positive direction, starting at positive real axis.
The square of the complex numbers without imaginary part is positive and has no imaginary part, but that is not true for complex numbers with non-zero imaginary part.

```
                                 X1^2
                                   \  
                                    \  
                                     \  
                                      \  
                                       0------------X2^2  
                                      /  
                                     /  
                                    /  
                                   /
                                 X3^2
```

The attribute "positive" is not defined for compley numbers. It is only defined for each of the two parts, the imaginary part and the real part.
The magnitude of a complex number is always >=0. But the magnitude is not neccessarily identical to the square of the complex number (or the square root of the square). 
There are two square roots for each complex number. Since they are 180° apart, one of them will always have negative real part, the other positive real part, or both are zero.

Whether there is one or more roots with zero imaginary part and positive real part (which seems to be what you mean when saying "positive") is something you will have to check by inspecting each of them. You can do that by getting all the powers 1..N-1 of the first root (which is the result for X^(1/N)). At least I do not know a shortcut for that.
Note that (as a comment made me aware) the numbers calculated are not the roots, but they have the same phase and therefor allow judging.

Comment: I cant follow you that I dont know why the (-10)^(2/3) have only a positive result and the (-10)^(1/3) have only a negative value.How can I judge the result is positive?

Comment: The result is complex, not positive. Of the three possible solutions the one with the smallest (positive) angle is returned as result. This is a consequence of implementing pow(z,w) as exp(w*Log(z)) where the complex logarithm uses the main branch.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thx but I dont know why (-10)^(2/3)!=((-10)^2)^(1/3)

Comment: @lindexi: The first is computed with an angle of 180°*2/3=120°, the second has an angle of 0° as positive real number which stays zero under division by 3.

Comment: Because (-10)^(2/3)!=(10^2)^(1/3)==((-10)^2)^(1/3).

Comment: @Yunnosch Looks like my math is poor.Can you Recommend me some books？

Comment: Sorry, no. I learnt from university scripts and some heavy tutoring.

Comment: The last section is not correct. To get all the possible solutions of Z^n=X use Z=X^(1/n) for the first and then multiply Z with powers of Q=(-1)^(2/N) to get the other roots.

Comment: @LutzL True. Thanks for alerting me. I incorporated your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This is getting into maths territory a bit too much for my comfort, but a magnitude will always be positive, as it is an Absolute value. A magnitude on it's own has no valuable meaning in the context of Complex number, because it includes an infinite number of points on a circle of radius `r=2.1544...` in this case.

Instead, you need to use both the Magnitude and the Argument (angle), or you can use the Real and Imaginary components.

If the angle is between -90° and 90° (0° is at the Real axis, going counter clockwise), then the Real component is positive, for angles between 0° and 180° the Imaginary component is positive

Comment: See the friendly documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.phase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @LutzL Thx ,but for a complex number a + bi, the phase is computed as Math.Atan2(b, a) that cant talk to is positive .

Answer (score 2):

There are two typical ways represent a complex number--either in Cartesian form or polar form.

```
Cartesian Form
  c = real + imaginary * i
Polar Form
  c = r * exp(i * theta)
```

The `r` here is the magnitude (`c.Magnitude`) and is one component that along with the angle (`c.Phase`) describes a point in the complex plane.

No ordering is defined on the complex set of numbers. You can ask if the real portion is positive. Alternatively you can ask if the imaginary component is positive.

```
c.Real > 0
c.Imaginary > 0
```

Comment: For c.Real is 1.0772173450159421 and c.Imag is 1.8657951723620641 but the true value isnt positive when I use `c = Complex.Pow(-10, 1.0/3)`